# Dynamic Header Titles with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering how I would go about being able to have different header titles using only 1 header file with React? I don't want to have to have a header for each component but want to have a title for each view that is changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: title as in `document.title`?

Comment: No, more of a title that I want to have for each document

Comment: Am new to react, how to render common header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what props are for.

```
// Header.js
const Header = ({ title }) => (
    <header>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
    </header>
);
```

Now you have a re-usable header component:

```
<Header title="Home" />

<Header title="About" />

<Header title="Contact" />
```

Comment: This works well while a having a simple header like that, but if you have a more complex header, would not be good to re-render it on every route/page change.

Comment: Optimising your renders is beyond the scope of the question. In any case, most of the page will typically re-render on a route change anyway.

Answer (score -1):

`{ title }` is the prop for the `Header` component, each view has a different title, e.g. `Ofertas` view: `title='Ofertas'`.